# Delete record using Bit map indexes

Tags: database, indexing, bitmap

The following table is given

[image]

Bitmap index on the attribute Salary are created, by dividing the values into 4 ranges:
below 50000, 50000 to below 60000, 60000 to below 70000, 70000 and above.

Also another bitmap index attribute on Dept was created.

The question asks whats the best option to delete employee with code 4? Clearly indicate if changes are required to be made to the bitmap indexes.

This is how I thought of the answer. Empoloyee with code 4 is in department CSE and salary 95,000

If Bitmap index on the attribute Salary are changed with more categories by extending the ranges with 70,000-80,000 and 80,000-90,000 and 90,000-95000 and 95,000 above, the bitmap index for 95,000 above will be

0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0

Dept with CSE index will be

1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0

Salary 0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
Dept   1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0

AND    0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0

Temporary
index  1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

AND    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

So the value is deleted.

If someone please let me know if this is correct or is there any other way

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way of doing deletion in a bitmap index is using an **existence bitmap**.

That is if the record exists the bit value is **1** and if the value doesn't exist the bit value is **0**.

So the existence bitmap for this scenario would be,

```
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Every query should be verified for existence. So the **AND** operation will always result **0** for the deleted records.